# Returning calling child instance from interface or class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, design-patterns

So this question is a clear case of one stone kills two birds (a design and code question) I have a base class which has a base interface

```
interface IBase
{
   IBase Method1();
}

abstract class Base : IBase
{
   IBase Method1()
   {
     //do work
     return this;
   }
}
```

Now the child class

```
interface IChild1 : IBase
{
  IChild1 ChildMethod();
}

class Child1 : Base, IChild1
{
  public IChild1 ChildMethod()
  {
    //do work 
    // this would work fine Method1(); ChildMethod2();
    //but I want to chain methods
    Method1().ChildMethod2();
    return this;
  }

  void ChildMethod2()
  {
    //do work
  }
}
```

The crux of the matter is I want the base class to return the child class instance. As you can tell from the code in the method ChildMethod(), the base class method Method1() returns the instance of IBase so chaining ChildMethod2() would not be possible. Yes I could live without having to chain the method, but lets assume that is my only option.

Here is my attempt at using generics

```
interface IBase<T> where T : IBase<T>
{
    T Method1();
}

abstract class Base<T> : IBase<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public T Method1()
    {
        //do work
        return (T)this;
    }
}

interface IChild1 : IBase<IChild1>
{
    IChild1 ChildMethod();
}

class Child1 : Base<Child1>, IChild1
{
    public IChild1 ChildMethod()
    {
        //do work
        Method1(); ChildMethod2();
        return this;
    }

    void ChildMethod2()
    {
        //do work
    }        
}
```

To put things clearly what I am trying to achieve is that for each call I make to the base class (interface in this case) I want the calling class/interface returned.
Note: Using Autofac for dependency injection

Comment: Does your generics example not work? That's how I would do it. You should be able to chain `Method1().ChildMethod2();`.

Comment: @ChrisPickford doesn't work

Comment: Do you really need both interfaces and parent classes together? Would be easy if you just had inheritance chain without interfaces. Generics in this case are also quite useless with interfaces, because you always need to specify some class when using them: `IBase<SomeBaseClass>`.

Comment: @Evk does it matter if I use an interface or not..?

Comment: You can do what you want in a relatively clear way if you don't use interfaces, only base class hierarchy. You can do that with interfaces too, but the way it will work (you will have to specify class when using an interface, like: `IChild1<Child1>`) will defeat the whole purpose of using those interfaces, so that's why I asking if you really need those interfaces or not.

Comment: @Evk I see your point but as u can see interfaces relate with interfaces. IChild1<Child1> doesn't apply

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it while preserving both interfaces and base class like this:

```
interface IBase<TSelf> where TSelf : IBase<TSelf> {
    TSelf Method1();
}

interface IChild1 : IBase<IChild1> {
    IChild1 ChildMethod();
    void ChildMethod2();
}

class Base<TSelf> : IBase<TSelf> where TSelf : IBase<TSelf> {
    public TSelf Method1() {
        //do work
        // need to double-cast here or just do            
        return (TSelf) (IBase<TSelf>) this;
    }
}

class Child1 : Base<IChild1>, IChild1 {
    public IChild1 ChildMethod() {
        //do work
        Method1().ChildMethod2();
        return this;
    }

    public void ChildMethod2() {
        //do work
    }
}
```

But as you noted in comments, this won't work with more members in inheritance tree. If you can remove interfaces, you can do it like this:

```
public abstract class Base<TSelf> where TSelf : Base<TSelf> {
    public TSelf Method1() {
        //do work
        // need to double-cast here or just do            
        return (TSelf) this;
    }
}

internal class Child1Impl<TSelf> : Base<TSelf> where TSelf : Child1Impl<TSelf> {
    public TSelf ChildMethod() {
        //do work
        Method1().ChildMethod2();
        return (TSelf) this;
    }

    public void ChildMethod2() {
        //do work
    }
}
// create subclass for ease of use, so that caller should not do Child1Impl<Child1> every time
class Child1 : Child1Impl<Child1> {

}

class SubChild1Impl<TSelf> : Child1Impl<TSelf> where TSelf : SubChild1Impl<TSelf> {
    public TSelf SubChildMethod() {
        Method1().ChildMethod();
        return (TSelf) this;
    }
}

class SubChild1 : SubChild1Impl<SubChild1> {

}
```

Then you can do:

```
var test = new SubChild1();
test.Method1().ChildMethod().SubChildMethod();
```

Maybe you can somehow do the same with interfaces, but code is already quite complicated, will be even more complicated with interfaces (and you already have base class, so maybe you don't really need those interfaces).

Comment: thanks Evk, but how would this look if I want to have a subclass of Child1, and a subclass of that..

Comment: subclassing Child1 would give class Child2 : Child1<Child2>, IChild2... thereby class Child1<T> : Base<IChild1<T>>, IChild1 where T : Child1<T>

Comment: Yes for more classes you can still do that, but code will become too ugly to consider it. Maybe it suggests you should reconsider your design somehow.

Comment: I guess so it sure would look ugly. So what you suggest if not use interfaces?

Comment: I've udpated answer showing how to do that without interfaces.